# Can I develop android applications using Eclipse IDE for Java EE?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I have downloaded Eclipse Helios for Java EE on my Mac. Now I want to develop an Android application. Can I use the same IDE for developing that android application?

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java EE to create webservices for applications. Also, now I got requirement to develop Android applications. Thats why, I want to use same IDE for both. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just need to get the Android SDK from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html Then you will need to get the Eclipse plug in by going to Help > Install New Software and input the link: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ . This will give you the plugin you need.

All this can be found here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Newest Android SDK's work with the newest versions of Eclipse(you would have a problem few months back, especially in Linux).

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
This is really informative. You can also find whatever you want to start developing. Have fun

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to. Just make sure you download the Android SDK and ADT.